# getaddrinfo for IPv6 always fails with error code 11268096

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, winsock

Edit: Upon Checking on [IPv6 Test](https://test-ipv6.com/) I Found out My ISP does not provide IPv6... otherwise this code is good

`getaddrinfo()` always fails for IPv6 with the error code 11268096, but it is successful for IPv4.

Setting `Hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;` is what triggers the error, but I do not know why.

Also, how do I get the `sin_port`/`sin6_port` in numbers? I am always getting port 0.(As @Remy Lebeau pointed out I am only asking for IP of the Domain so it won't output port...)

```
void GetAddrInfoFromHostNameIPV6(const char* DomainName, addrinfo* Result, bool& IsSuccessful)
{
    IsSuccessful = false;
    addrinfo Hint;
    addrinfo* Return = nullptr;
    int ErrorCode;

    memset(&Hint, 0, sizeof(Hint));
    Hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    Hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    //Hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    ErrorCode = getaddrinfo(DomainName, NULL, &Hint, &Return) << '\n';
    if (ErrorCode != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\n Error GetAddrInfoFromHostNameIPV6() Failed with Error Code: " << ErrorCode << " in GetAddrInfoFromHostName In: NW_P!";
    }
    else
    {
        *Result = *Return;
        char IpAddress[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        uint16_t Port;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &((sockaddr_in6*)((Result)->ai_addr))->sin6_addr, IpAddress, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        Port = *(&((sockaddr_in6*)(Result->ai_addr))->sin6_port);
        std::cout << "\n IPV6 Address of Domain '" << DomainName << "' Is " << IpAddress << " With Port: " << Port;

        IsSuccessful = true;
    }

    if (!IsSuccessful)// For the safe of readability
    {
        std::cout << "\n Error GetAddrInfoFromHostName() Failed in NW_P!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser/blob/master/source/acceptorconnector.cpp and related. It will handle IPV4 and IPV6. May be you can get some idea . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny Thank you! i will look into it!

Answer (score 4):

You are bit-shifting the error code 10 bits to the left before assigning it to `ErrorCode`.

Decimal `11268096` is binary `101010111111000000000000`. Notice all those extra zeros on the right?

You need to get rid of `<< '\n'` after `getaddrinfo()` returns, it doesn't belong there, as you are not outputting the error code to `std::cout` on that line of code.

Removing the bit shifting, the real error code is `11004` (binary `10101011111100`) which is [`WSANO_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2):

> Valid name, no data record of requested type.The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for. The usual example for this is a host name-to-address translation attempt (using `gethostbyname` or `WSAAsyncGetHostByName`) which uses the DNS (Domain Name Server). An MX record is returned but no A record—indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly reachable.

You can pass the error code to `gai_strerror()` to get a human-readable string for your error message output, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << "\n Error GetAddrInfoFromHostNameIPV6() Failed with Error Code: " << ErrorCode << " (" << gai_strerror(ErrorCode) << ") in GetAddrInfoFromHostName In: NW_P!";
```

As for the port number being 0, you are not asking `getaddrinfo()` to parse any service name/port string as input (the `pServiceName` parameter is NULL), you are only asking for translating a domain name into an IP, so it is not going to output any port number. Port numbers are not used by Domains themselves. Port numbers are used by services (HTTP, etc) that are running on servers where domains/IPs point to.

---

On a side note, you are leaking the `addrinfo`  list that `getaddrinfo()` outputs. You need to call `freeaddrinfo()` when you are done using the list.

Comment: Hello! and thanks for answering! but what "host itself exists, but is not directly reachable" I don't understand... i Simply changed ipv4 to ipv6, shouldn't it work the same?
Also thanks for telling me about the bitshift! did not notice it!

Comment: @PunalManalan it means the domain name exists but does not resolve to an IPv6 address. Not all domains support IPv6.

Comment: yes but google has ipv6 domain right? it should work right?

Comment: @PunalManalan yes, Google has an IPv6 address. Is that what you are passing in the `DomainName` parameter? It would have helped if you had provided a [mcve] in your question. Please edit your question to do so.

Comment: @PunalManalan what does the command `nslookup google.com` show ?

Comment: @RichardCritten on some systems, there is a difference between what `getaddrinfo()` can resolve vs what `nslookup` can resolve, because they use different techniques to get their info.

Comment: Iam sorry for Late reply it was Over 1AM here... had to sleep!

Comment: @RichardCritten It shows 
`Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4007:81c::200e
          142.250.182.110`

Comment: @PunalManalan that looks like a reply from a local DNS server on a LAN router (possibly a cached IP), not even from an Internet provider.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then how can i get IPv6 using getadderinfo()?

Comment: @PunalManalan the code shown is fine, once you fix the issues mentioned. The real problem is environmental, your network is not resolving the IPv6 address via DNS correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately i have been looking at every possible forum and still no luck on how to fix the IPv6 network problem...

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think this is a problem on my ISP part [https://test-ipv6.com/](IPv6 Test) 
This is what it says "Your DNS server (possibly run by your ISP) appears to have no access to the IPv6 Internet, or is not configured to use it. This may in the future restrict your ability to reach IPv6-only sites"